# How to fix nodejs is not showing flash message

Tags: node.js, validation, express, connect-flash

I am using express and I am making a signup page connected to mongo database, I made it that when a user types the same email as another user it flashes a message using connect-flash "Email is already in use" but it is not showing on my website, even tho I put another flash message "Invalid email" and it worked.

index.js Code:

```
router.get('/user/signup', function(req, res, next) {
  var messages = req.flash('error');
  res.render('user/signup', {csrfToken: req.csrfToken(), messages : messages, hasErrors: messages.length > 0});
});
```

passport.js Code:

```
passport.use('local.signup', new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField : 'email',
  passwordField : 'password',
  passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, email, password, done){
  req.checkBody('email', 'Invalid email').notEmpty().isEmail();
  req.checkBody('password', 'Invalid password').notEmpty().isLength({min:4});
  var errors = req.validationErrors();
  if (errors) {
    var messages = []
    errors.forEach(function(error) {
      messages.push(error.msg);
    });
    return done(null, false, req.flash('error', messages));
  }
  User.findOne({'email': email}, function(err, user){
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }
    if (user) {
      return done(null, false, {message: 'Email is already in use'});
    }
    var newUser = new User();
    newUser.email = email;
    newUser.password = newUser.encryptPassword(password);
    newUser.save(function(err, result){
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      return done(null, newUser);
    });
  });
}));
```

Comment: Try ` if (user) {return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'Email is already in use'));}`

Comment: Thank you it worked